# Previous and next date using jquery (ajax) and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some kind of calendar written in php with previous and next buttons. Now I want to use some ajax to go to the previous or next date without refreshing the page.

In the php file called by ajax I have a query which returns the tasks for a selected day (something like : `...WHERE date = $date`).

The problem is that I can't get to the day before today and so on, and to the day after today and so on.

Someone who can help?

**EDIT**

Buttons:

```
<button class='btn btn-default previous' data-date='$date'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>   
</button>
<button class='btn btn-default next' data-date='$date'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.previous').click(function() {
        var date = $(this).data('date');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { action : "previous" , date: date },
            url: "includes/ajax/plannerdata.php",               
            success: function(returnData){                    
                $("#planner-data").html(returnData);
            }
        });
    });
    $('button.next').click(function() {
    var date = $(this).data('date');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: 'next', date: date },
            url: "includes/ajax/plannerdata.php",               
            success: function(returnData){                    
                $("#planner-data").html(returnData); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

plannerdata.php:

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'next':
        $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($_POST['date'] .' -1 day'));
        break;
    case 'previous':
        $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($_POST['date'] .' +1 day'));
        break;
}
```

And then I use $date in my query.

**UPDATED plannerdata.php:**

```
if (!isset ($_POST['date'])) { // At first page load or refresh (without using the previous/next buttons), plannerdata.php is also loaded bij ajax and injected in index.php
    $currentDatetime = new DateTime('NOW');
}
else { // Previous or next button is pressed
    $currentDatetime = new DateTime($_POST['date']);
}

    $dateModification = $_POST['action'];

    switch ($dateModification) {
        case 'previous':
            $currentDatetime->modify('-1 day');
            break;
        case 'next':
            $currentDatetime->modify('+1 day');
            break;
    }
    $date = $currentDatetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

**EDIT**

**plannerdata.php;**

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['date'])) {
    $_SESSION['date'] = new DateTime('NOW');
}

if (isset ($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'previous':
            $_SESSION['date']->modify('-1 day');
            break;
        case 'next':
            $_SESSION['date']->modify('+1 day');
            break;
    }
}

$date = $_SESSION['date']->format('Y-m-d');
```

**buttons (inside index.php). I removed the data-date attribute:**

```
<button class='btn btn-default previous'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button class='btn btn-default next'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
```

The buttons are inside an  and between both buttons the selected date is shown.

```
<ul>
    <li>button previous</li>
    <li><span id="planner_date">selected date</span></li>
    <li>button next</li>
<ul>
```

**I also changed the Jquery. I make a simultaneous ajax call.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.previous').click(function() {
        $.when(
                $.post("includes/ajax/plannerdata.php", {action: 'previous'}, function(data) {
                    plannerData = data;
                }),
                $.post("includes/ajax/date.php", {action: 'previous'}, function(date) {
                    calendardate = date;
                })
        ).then(function() {
            $("#planner-data").html(plannerData);
            $("#planner_date").text(calendardate);
        });
    });
    $('button.next').click(function() {
        $.when(
                $.post("includes/ajax/plannerdata.php", {action: 'next'}, function(data) {
                    plannerData = data;
                }),
                $.post("includes/ajax/date.php", {action: 'next'}, function(date) {
                    calendardate = date;
                })
        ).then(function() {
            $("#planner-data").html(plannerData);
            $("#planner_date").text(calendardate);
        });
    });
});
```

**Date.php for returning the current date:**

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['current_date'])) {
    $_SESSION['current_date'] = new DateTime('NOW');
}

if (isset ($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'previous':
            $_SESSION['current_date']->modify('-1 day');
            break;
        case 'next':
            $_SESSION['current_date']->modify('+1 day');
            break;
    }
}

$date = $_SESSION['current_date']->format('Y-m-d');
echo $date;
```

**EDIT 2015-03-05:**

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.previous').click(function() {
        $.when(
            $.post("includes/ajax/date.php", 
                {action: 'previous'}, 
                function(date) {
                   dates = jQuery.parseJSON(date);
                   calendardate = dates.dutch;

                    $.post("includes/ajax/plannerdata.php", 
                        {date: dates.sql},
                        function(data) {
                            plannerData = data;
                        })
                    })
                    ).then(function(){
                $("#planner_date").text(calendardate);
                $("#planner-data").html(plannerData);
            });
        });
});
```

**date.php**

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['current_date'])) {
    $_SESSION['current_date'] = new DateTime('NOW');
}
if (isset ($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'previous':
            $_SESSION['current_date']->modify('-1 day');
            break;
        case 'next':
            $_SESSION['current_date']->modify('+1 day');
            break;
    }
}
$date_1 = $_SESSION['current_date']->format('Y-m-d');
$date_2 = $_SESSION['current_date']->format('d-m-Y');
$response = array('sql' => $date_1, 'dutch' => $date_2);
echo json_encode($response);
```

**UPDATE 2015-03-08**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.previous').click(function() {
        var calendardate;
        var plannerData;
        $.when(
            $.post("includes/ajax/date.php", 
                {action: 'previous'}, 
                function(date) {
                   dates = jQuery.parseJSON(date)
                   calendardate = dates.dutch;

                    $.post("includes/ajax/plannerdata.php", 
                            {date: dates.sql},
                            function(data) {
                               plannerData = data;
                            })}
                        )).then(function(){
                $("#planner_date").text(calendardate)
                $("#planner-data").html(plannerData);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Please include the code.  Otherwise it will be almost impossible to actually fix the problem(s).

Comment: Very good idea with using [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see, best for you should be using [PHP DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php). You can modify your script to something like this:

```
$dateModification=$_POST['action'];//for clarification
//Datetime understands every format strtotime does
$currentDatetime=new DateTime($_POST['date']);

switch ($dateModification) {
    case 'next':
        $currentDateTime->modify("+1 day");//simple, isn't it?
        break;
    case 'previous':
        $currentDateTime->modify("-1 day");
        break;
}
//final result
$date=$currentDateTime->format("Y-m-d");
```

With DateTime you can easily manipulate dates as objects. It's also possible to compare two Datetime objects with < > == signs as easy as:

```
$firstDatetime=new Datetime("2015-02-20");
$secondDatetime=new Datetime("2015-02-25");
if ($firstDatetime<$secondDatetime)
{
    echo '$firstDatetime was indeed first!';
}
```

Try it out yourself :)

**EDIT - How to handle date modifications on server side:**

Few more thoughts about it. Your updated code is making two AJAX calls to server, both of them are modifying datetime object. As it would work, it's duplicating code. Let's try to modify calls and script to work on just one DateTime object. Let's move date modification to your `date.php` and `plannerdata.php` will be working on same date variable.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.previous').click(function() {
        $.post("includes/ajax/date.php", 
            {action: 'previous'}, 
            function(date) {
                dates = jQuery.parseJSON(date)
                $("#planner_date").text(dates.dutch)
                $.post("includes/ajax/plannerdata.php", 
                    {date: dates.sql},
                    function(data) {
                        $("#planner-data").html(data);
                    })
            })
    })
});
```

**PHP:**

Date.php will remain the same, we must change just plannerdata.php to use same variable:

```
//we remove that block, as it will be set in date.php
/*if (!isset ($_SESSION['date'])) {
    $_SESSION['date'] = new DateTime('NOW');
}

if (isset ($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'previous':
            $_SESSION['date']->modify('-1 day');
            break;
        case 'next':
            $_SESSION['date']->modify('+1 day');
            break;
    }
}*/

$date = $_SESSION['current_date']->format('Y-m-d');
```

That should be it! :)

**How to create DateTime from specific format?:**

For such purposes exist function [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.createfromformat.php). Example usage:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "nl_NL");//firstly we need to setlocale, so month names will be properly recognized
$dateString='6 maart 2015';
$datetime=DateTime::createFromFormat("j F Y", $dateString);
```

This will return datetime object, which you can operate on.

Comment: Sorry, it took a while.. I didn't know about DateTime() yet, so, thank you! Very nice, and easy in use. But I still have a problem... I can't get the `data-date` attribute in the next/previous buttons updated with the new date... So it stays like `<button class='btn btn-default previous' data-date='2015-03-03'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>   
</button>` You can see my updated plannerdata.php in my question ;)

Comment: I also can't access $_POST['date'] in my index.php. You can see my updated plannerdata.php in my question ;)

Comment: @JK87 - it should be achievable, but i need more info. Do i correctly assume, that your `plannerdata.php` returning some HTML which you're inserting into webpage? (we can try to get with it our new calculated date, or calculate it on JS side)

Also - what does it mean that you can't access $_POST['date']? Your JS is, indeed doing POST to it.

Comment: That's right, the plannerdata.php returns a html-table inside a `<div>` in the index.php. What about accessing `$_POST['date']` in the index.php: it returns a 'unindentified index' error.. At the moment I tried to use sessions. One session to store the current date to query the database inside plannerdata.php and one inside date.php to return the current-date in my index.php. Both sessions are unset on a logout. So far it works perfect, or could I get in trouble this way somehow? You can see the updated code in my question (second edit)

Comment: @JK87 - i returned home and what i see? That what i would suggest - make two calls to server. Javascript, as it is client-side script can be irraliable - PHP script will always work the same for all of your clients. So tell me, what problems do you still have?

Comment: It works perfect now! Only I was a bit unsure about the sessions approach.. What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: @JK87 - i suggested one modification to your actual code :) Remember to change also jquery handling for next-button (i attached example for previous)

Comment: Thanks again! The reason that I used 2 `DateTime()` objects was because in the query in plannerdata.php in need a 'Y-m-d' format, but the calendardate I would like to have in the 'd-m-Y' notation (notation in NL) I tried to edit your code a little (above..) and also the date.php. I think Json can help. The point where I get stuck is: when I click on a button (after pageload) the calendardate is updated as it should, but I also get the js-error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: plannerData is not defined` when I go any further the date in plannerdata is 1 day behind on the calenderdate..

Comment: @JK87 - first of all, as you're storing DateTime object in session variable - you can format it as you want (y-md or d-m-Y according to your needs). plannerData in JS was, indeed, undefined - i added definition right before calling `$.when`, now it should be properly defined outside of ajax callback

Comment: Almost.. I just want to go one step further: write the 'dutch date' not just d-m-y but like '6 maart 2015'. So my `$date_2` variable in date.php is not `$date_2 = $_SESSION['current_date']->format('d-m-Y');` but `$datum_2 = strftime('%A %#d %B %Y', strtotime($datum_1));` I think I do need json because the `calendardate` is injected into `#planner_datum`-span and I can't format the date after the injection.. or? And `DateTime()` does not accept `new DateTime('6 maart 2015')`. The `plannerData` is indeed defined now, only the html is not injected/updated in the `#planner-data' div..

Comment: @JK87 - It's getting more complicated, but i added to my answer sample code to create from any format. Can you update your question to contain your current jquery code?

Comment: I updated the code. As I said, the html-response from 'plannerData' is somehow not injected in the #planner-data div.. But I can see the response in the development tools from Chrome.. Any idea?

Comment: @JK87 - I assume, that' something with variables being not set on time. As our code get a little complicate - i simplified it. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and patience!! Everything works as it should now! :) I will also tryout `DateTime::createFromFormat`! :)

Comment: I think, that in all that trying my answer got a little chaotic view :D You're welcome

Comment: So was my question haha. You've been a great help so don't worry :D

Answer (score 0):

Use INTERVAL, for example:

TOMORROW:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = $date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

YESTERDAY

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = $date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```